# Sunspot/Solr Scope by array field

Tags: solr, sunspot, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I have an array of tags in my class, I would like to scope a fulltext search to only return objects if they contain one of several values in the tags array. Not sure if this is possible since there are multiple tags and multiple scoping values.

```
class Video
  include Sunspot::Mongoid2

  field :categories, type: Array, default: [] # array of strings
  field :description, type: String, default: ""
  field :title, type: String, default: ""

  searchable do #these fields will be indexed by sunspot/solr
    text :title
    text :description
    string :categories # this seems wrong but there is no array field type?????
  end
end
```

This seems wrong since there is no `array` field type and the array of strings is not the same as `string`.

However the fulltext query I'd like to make is something like this:

```
search = Video.search do
  fulltext params[:q] do
    fields :title, :description
  end
  with(:categories, ["Netflix", "Amazon"])
end
@videos = search.results
```

Again, this is because `categories` will often have multiple values so the object may have:

```
video.categories = ["Horror", "Drama", "Netlfix"]
```

and I'd like this object to be returned if the `fulltext` matches with the above categories matching at least one of the `with(:categories, ["Netflix", "Amazon"])`

Is there a way to do this in Sunspot?

Answer (score 3):

Running rake sunspot:solr:reindex gave the clue to solving this. It said categories was not multi-valued. So the following solved it:

```
  searchable do #these fields will be indexed by sunspot/solr
    text :title
    text :description
    string :categories, multiple: true
  end
```

and the reindex and query work.